# Is it appropriate to express a sentence without verb?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, questions

Many native speakers expressing sentences **without verbs** while speaking,
For instance,

- What you doing now?
- How you doing?

Is it appropriate?

Comment: No verb in this sentence.

Comment: I like the greeting *What up?* :D

Answer (score 3):

Spoken language differs in many ways from written language. Those utterances would certainly occur in the spoken English of native speakers and to that extent they are ‘appropriate’. Incidentally, each contains a verb, even if it is a non-finite one.

Comment: Exactly spoken and written language lives different lives. On the other hand there are a lot of slang expressions that are OK in spoken language but you might find them only in novels in written language. Although I can't agree with your native speakers as there are a lot of people using English nowadays and they are not native. It is impossible to find someone that his bread and butter requires some computer knowledge without being able to speak English.

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, it is wrong and formally should be "What are you doing?" and "How are you doing?".

These can be shortened to "What're you doing?" and "How're you doing?" and then it becomes a matter of pronunciation and hearing: in some cases the *'re* can be almost silent and not heard, and so transcribed by the listener apparently without a verb.

There are alternatives: I imagine these may be the origin of "Whatcha" and not that far away from "Howdy", though the latter is more probably from "How do you do?".

Comment: I'm sure,In many hollywood movies, they are using without verbs even in subtitles.

Comment: @Vijin: Using -what- without verbs?

Comment: @Mitch,Expressing sentences without verbs.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: Oh...you used a prepositional phrase as a modifier without a thing modified (which sounds weird in English). As to sentences without verbs, look at the utterances in (and subtitles to) movies in your native language. There will be lots of them that don't have a verb. It all depends on the utterance. In English you can have a noun phrase all by itself , but it'll sounds weird to have two noun phrases (even a 'to be' (copula) is needed, unless you slur through it.)

Comment: @Mitch,You mean it's acceptable in spoken English?Of course, my native language also don't have verbs in the spoken form and the literature forms are completely difference from the spoken language.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: It all depends on what you mean by 'it'. In spoken English, a stand a lone noun phrase is very acceptable (as an answer to a question) but is not acceptable in written English. In your examples, they are fine spoken (and identify  as  having an unheard 'are' or being dialect (Southern AmE or AAVE)) but neither are OK written.